# Quarterly industry-level productivity growth?

Tags: labor-economics, data-request, productivity

Are there any quarterly data on industry-level productivity growth (i.e., by NAICS code) in the United States? I've looked around for a while but haven't been able to find anything. BLS publishes aggregate productivity growth quarterly, so I find it hard to believe that there isn't a breakdown by industry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://beta.bls.gov/dataQuery/find?fq=survey:[ip]&s=popularity:D) is exactly what you are looking for, at the finest level of NAICS disagregation.

Example for aircraft manufacturing:

[image]

Example for Software publishers:

[image]